# How are state channels being implemented (MetaMask?)

Tags: metamask, ecrecover

I've been trying to get MetaMask to produce a signature for a sha3 hash that I can verify in solidity. I've tried eth_sign, personal_sign, eth_signTypedData, and I've had `0` success.

My test suite runs fine (Truffle), but I can not for the life of me get MetaMask to play nice, and I can't find a working example anywhere.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you came across this? https://danfinlay.github.io/js-eth-personal-sign-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: https://github.com/ConnextProject/ethcalate-2waypayment/blob/master/contracts/ChannelManager.sol

Relevant code:

```
bytes32 fingerprint = keccak256(channelId, nonce, balanceA, balanceB);
bytes32 signTypedDataFingerprint = keccak256(
    keccak256("bytes32 hash"),
    keccak256(fingerprint)
);
require(ECTools.isSignedBy(signTypedDataFingerprint, sigA, channel.agentA) == true);
```

This is what we do on the client/dapp side (https://github.com/ConnextProject/ethcalate-client/blob/master/src/Ethcalate.js):

```
async signTx ({ channelId, nonce, balanceA, balanceB }) {
  // fingerprint = keccak256(channelId, nonce, balanceA, balanceB)
  let hash = abi
    .soliditySHA3(
      ['bytes32', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'],
      [channelId, nonce, balanceA, balanceB]
    )
    .toString('hex')
  hash = `0x${hash}`
  console.log('hash: ', hash)

  const sig = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
      {
        method: 'eth_signTypedData',
        params: [
          [
            {
              type: 'bytes32',
              name: 'hash',
              value: hash
            }
          ],
          this.web3.eth.accounts[0]
        ],
        from: this.web3.eth.accounts[0]
      },
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) reject(err)
        if (result.error) {
          reject(result.error.message)
        }
        resolve(result)
      }
    )
  })
  console.log('sig: ', sig)
  return sig
}
```

Comment: Does this result in a Metamask prompt per channel update?

Comment: Yes it does for Metamask. However, there will surely be other wallet implementations which have different ways to handle this. Spankchain's browser wallet autosigns channel update transactions.